# DirectX: How to apply an Effect to a texture drawn with ID3DXSprite.Draw(..)

Tags: xna, directx, shader, effect

I want to write a very simple **Effect** for a **DirectX** program which uses the **ID3DXSprite** interface to draw a **2D-Hud**. In XNA I simply called

```
        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteBlendMode.AlphaBlend, SpriteSortMode.Immediate, SaveStateMode.None);

        effect.Begin();
        effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Rectangle(0, 0, 300, 300), Color.White);
        effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].End();
        effect.End();

        spriteBatch.End();
```

But in C++, nearly the same code doesnt work

```
pSprite->Begin(D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND | D3DXSPRITE_DONOTSAVESTATE | D3DXSPRITE_SORT_TEXTURE);

anEffect->SetTechnique(technique);

anEffect->Begin(&passes, 0);

anEffect->BeginPass(0);

pSprite->Draw(pTexture, NULL, NULL, &position, 0xFFFFFFFF);

anEffect->EndPass();

anEffect->End();

pSprite->End();
```

**NOTE: The effect is loaded  correctly!**

Comment: What does it draw?  Sprites with just the texture and no effect?  Nothing at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all the XNA code you have is for XNA 3.1, *and it's wrong*. [This blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/04/05/spritebatch-and-custom-shaders-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx) explains how to do it for both XNA 3.1 and 4.0 (the API [changes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/04/05/spritebatch-and-custom-renderstates-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx) in between).

In XNA 3.1, when using `SpriteSortMode.Immediate`, `SpriteBatch` will set up its shaders and other device state in the `Begin` call, instead of in the `End` call. This gives you the opportunity to replace parts of the device state before drawing actually takes place (in `Draw` or `End`, depending on when it flushes). And then you are supposed to `End` your effect ***after*** you `End` the sprite batch (so everything gets drawn first).

Now, in DirectX, I would suggest that the same incorrect ordering of your `End` calls is to blame. Specifically refer to this part of the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb205815(v=VS.85).aspx) for the second parameter to `ID3DXEffect::Begin`

> determines if state modified by an effect is saved and restored. The default value 0 specifies that ID3DXEffect::Begin and ID3DXEffect::End will save and restore all state modified by the effect

The upshot is that, when you `End` the effect, it is resetting the device back to normal sprite drawing, before you call `End` on the `ID3DXSprite`, which is what is actually sending your sprite batch to be drawn.

I would guess that the reason your incorrectly-ordered code works on XNA is that XNA is probably doing the equivalent of passing `D3DXFX_DONOTSAVESTATE`, when beginning the effect, under the hood.

Answer (score -1):

**Usage of Sprite with HLSL Effect: (for C++ Game Developers)**

Below is the sample code which explains how sprite draw can work with HLSL effect files

***Pseudo Code:***

```
ID3DXEffect*                g_pEffect = NULL;       // D3DX effect interface

void loadTextureEffect() {     
  D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(gD3dDevice,L"image.png",&gTextureBackdrop);
  DWORD dwShaderFlags = D3DXFX_NOT_CLONEABLE;
  D3DXCreateEffectFromFile( gD3dDevice, "shader.fx", NULL, NULL, dwShaderFlags,
                                    NULL, &g_pEffect, NULL );
}

void Render()
{
   unsigned int passes;
   gD3dDevice->Clear(0, 0, D3DCLEAR_TARGET | D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER, 0x00000000, 1.0f, 0);
   gD3dDevice->BeginScene();
   gSprite->Begin(0);
   g_pEffect->SetTechnique("PostProcess"); 
   g_pEffect->SetTexture( "Tex0", gTextureBackdrop );
   float blurFactor = 25;   
   g_pEffect->SetValue("TextureBlur",&blurFactor ,sizeof(float));   
   g_pEffect->Begin(&passes, 0);
   for(unsigned int pass = 0; pass < passes; ++pass)
   {
    g_pEffect->BeginPass(pass);
    D3DXVECTOR3 spritePos(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    gD3dDevice->SetTexture(0,gTextureBackdrop);
    gSprite->Draw(gTextureBackdrop, 0, 0, &spritePos, 0xffffffff);
    gSprite->End();  
    g_pEffect->CommitChanges();
    g_pEffect->EndPass();
   }
g_pEffect->End();   
gD3dDevice->EndScene();
gD3dDevice->Present(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
}
```